# How to iterate through a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ID  Date    flag_14  flag_21
1   1/1/2013    1     1
1   1/16/2013   1     0
1   1/19/2013   0     0
1   1/23/2013   0     1
1   1/26/2013   0     0
2   1/1/2013    1     1    
2   1/18/2013   1     0
```

Hi, 
I am sorry this may be a stupid question but I really could use some help.
So I want to create the above output. the first 2 columns are input (id and date). The logic is to use 14 days and 21 days as cutoffs to decide whether a record is kept within same id by comparing the dates of current record and last kept one. the first record for each id is always kept (flag is 1 to indicate "keep", 0 indicates otherwise) .

For example, for id 1, if the cutoff is 21, the second record's date is 1/16/2013, which is 15 days after the previous kept one (which is the first record 1/1/2013), 15<21 so the flag for second record is 0. Same for the third record, 1/19/2013 and 1/1/2013 are 18 days apart, 18<21 so flag =0. But for the 4th record, 1/23/2013 and 1/1/2013 are 22 days apart, 22>21, so this record is kept, flag=1. Then 5th record is to be compared with the last kept one (now is the 4th record) , 1/26/2013 and 1/23/2013 are 3 days apart, 3<21, so flag =0.

Is there a simple to iterate this using something like `partition by`?

Thanks!!

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server? This can be solved more easily in 2012 that has implemented new analytic function (LAG, LEAD, etc.)

Comment: I have 2008 version unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

**Please Try it ,, It's Working as per question**

```
with cte as
(
select o.*
from( 
    select  yourid,yourdate,ROW_NUMBER () Over (partition by yourid order by (select(0)) ) as RN
    from sedata 
    ) as o 
),
cte2 as
(
select r.*,
    case when  r.RN %2=0
    then
    (select DAY(r.YourDate) - DAY(r1.YourDate) where r.yourid = r1.yourid) 
    else
   (select DAY( r.YourDate) - DAY(min(YourDate)) from sedata where r.yourid = r1.yourid )
    end as Total   


 from cte r left  join cte r1 ON r.RN-1 = r1.RN  
 )
 select *
  ,case when   Total is null then 1 when Total >14 and Total <21 then 1   else 0  end as flag_14 ,
   case when  Total is null then 1 when Total > 21 then 1   else 0  end  as flag_21

  from cte2   where Total is not null or RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about ordering the data based on date, like in your example, we can use something similar to the below code (note, I'm only using YourID and YourDate fields):

```
CREATE TABLE SeData(
    YourID INT,
    YourDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO SeData
VALUES (1,'2013-01-01')
 , (1,'2013-01-16')
 , (1,'2013-01-19')
 , (1,'2013-01-23')
 , (1,'2013-01-26')

;WITH Roll AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YourDate) ID
        , YourID
        , YourDate
    FROM SeData
)
SELECT *
    , (DAY(r1.YourDate) - DAY(r.YourDate)) AS NumberBetween -- just an example of comparing
FROM Roll r
    INNER JOIN Roll r1 ON r.ID = (r1.ID - 1)
```

From there, you can compare the day from r to r1 and update/insert what you need.

**Update:** I know this works on `2012` (though it has `LAG` and `LEAD`), `2008R2` and not sure it runs on 2005 or below.

Comment: This doesn't produce the `flag14` and `flag21` columns that the OP wants.

Comment: thanks!!  but I need to compare not only with the previous date. I need to compare with the last kept record's date, so one more layer is needed...I am struggling with that layer...